# Build failed use of deprecated Android v2 embedding

Tags: android, flutter, tflite

There is this error whenI am trying to insert TFLite plugin in dependencies in pubspec.yaml  that causes the build to fail how to fix this error.

> The plugin `tflite` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding. To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs. If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

Comment: Someone needs to update the plugin.  Unless you're capable of and willing to do that for the author, your only choice is whether or not to find another library that isn't at risk of breaking in the future.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing we can do in this case. Flutter told us already & very clear in your error above. Try to use other plugin, such as `tflite_flutter`. I see this plugin is updated regularly, by TensorFlow.

Comment: if I used tflite_flutter instead of tflite, could I work without any problem? are both features the same

Comment: I think its features are more specific & have well documentation. Because it is developed by author TensorFlow itself. You should use the plugin that has more usage & well-updated.